# Individual boxes instead of regular table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

So, I have to make a table in HTML and the code I used works fine but the table is not how I wanted it to be. As you can see below, inside the table are individual boxes including the text. I want to make it like a normal table! How do I do that? Thanks

The results of the code

[image]

Comment: How do you define a "normal table"? Please [edit] your question to include the source code you currently have and a screenshot of how the table should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The border-collapse property will make your table have united cells. See this example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Example</th>
    <th>Table</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Add this css property to your table, th and td elements to collapse the borders:

```
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding "this should work..." as answers provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this using css grid

```html
 <div class="grid">
    <div class="span-2">a</div>
    <div class="span-2">b</div>
    <div class="span-2">c</div>
    <div class="span-3">d</div>
    <div>e</div>

    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>-</div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}

.span-3 {
  grid-column-start: span 3;
}
```

Here is a codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-grid-example-52wzp